# foreach loop modifies an array without I want

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I don't understand what happens, I have an array of **associative arrays**, and I want to iterate through it so I made a foreach loop but this loop **modified** my initial array and I don't know why, loot at the code :

- 1st case

```php
var_dump($modules);
$tab = $modules;
foreach ($tab as $module){
   var_dump($module);
}
```

The result :
[image]

On the left, is the initial array and at the right : the different values of the array. As you can see, it doesn't show the second one item but only the one. If I show the $tab inside of the loop, it is just an array of 2 items containing twice copies of the "jojo" item .

- 2nd case

However, if I write this :

```php
for($i=0;$i<count($tab);$i++){
   var_dump($tab[$i]);
}
```

It works fine as I want
[image]

and if I execute the for loop after the foreach loop the result is the same as the 1st case. Do you knwo why ?

Comment: Your foreach-snippet would not result in that output. There must be something happening inside the foreach that overrides `$tab`. You should edit you code and add everything that could be relevant.

Comment: But I just show the variable inside of the foreach ...  I don't understand

Comment: Can't reproduce you issue: https://3v4l.org/0KNTi There must be something else going on that we can't see.